# Php Variable auto increasing number

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure exactly how to word it, but I am trying to input a caption along with photograph. The `for()` autoincreases and coincides with the field name.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=21;$i++) {
        if (file_exists(ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/fsrep/houses/additional/small/'.$ListingDetails->listing_id.'-'.$i.'.jpg')) {
            if (($ListingDetails->listing_caption."_".$i) != '' ) {$ListingCaption = ($ListingDetails->listing_caption.'_'.$i);} else{$ListingCaption = 'View Slideshow';}
            $AdditionalImages .= '<td align="center" valign="center"><a href="'.get_option('home').'/wp-content/uploads/fsrep/houses/additional/large/'.$ListingDetails->listing_id.'-'.$i.'.jpg" title="'.$ListingCaption.'" rel="lightbox[slideshow]" onmouseover="document.getElementById(\'fsrep-main-image-img\').src=\''.get_option('home').'/wp-content/uploads/fsrep/houses/additional/'.$ListingDetails->listing_id.'-'.$i.'.jpg\'; document.getElementById(\'fsrep-main-image-a\').rel=\'lightbox[slideshow]\'" onmouseout="document.getElementById(\'fsrep-main-image-img\').src=\''.get_option('home').'/wp-content/uploads/fsrep/houses/'.$ListingDetails->listing_id.'.jpg\'; document.getElementById(\'fsrep-main-image-a\')"><img src="'.get_option('home').'/wp-content/uploads/fsrep/houses/additional/small/'.$ListingDetails->listing_id.'-'.$i.'.jpg" class="full" /></a></td>';
            if ($i == 7 || $i == 14|| $i == 21) {
                $AdditionalImages .= '</tr><tr>';
            }
        }
    }
```

I am tying to get it to output the `$listing_caption` correctly, but it isn't reading the field name as for example `$ListingDetails->listing_caption_1` instead I think it is reading it as `$ListingDetails->listing_caption`, but I am not sure.

The fields in the mysql database are for example:

```
listing_caption_1, listing_caption_2, listing_caption_3, etc.
```

Comment: what is `$ListingDetails`? is it row from `mysql_fetch_row`?

Comment: This in fact has nothing at all to do with photos, or auto-increasing numbers, or databases. It's just a question about how to use a variable with a dynamic name. Please narrow down your question to a _minimal_ issue next time!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal To quote the first thing I wrote "I am not sure exactly how to word it". Thank you for your contribution to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$capt_num = "listing_caption".'_'.$i;
$ListingCaption = $ListingDetails->$capt_num;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your `$ListingDetails` is, but if it represents a database, and you populate it with say, `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, you can turn:

```
$ListingCaption = ($ListingDetails->listing_caption.'_'.$i);
```

into:

```
$ListingCaption = $ListingDetails['listing_caption_'.$i];
```

Assuming that's where you're having trouble.